# Setting up a jdbc connection pool for sybase

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, tomcat, sap-ase

I am currently creating a jdbc connection for every jsp or servlet.

How can I create a jdbc connection pool for sybase such that the need for creating the connection for every jsp/servlet can be avoided and the jsp/servlet can directly get the connection and transact with the database.

Can anyone provide step-by-step instructions for setting up of the same and also how to use it.

And the pool should be able to handle a commercial website.

Comment: Wow, you're not asking for much, are you?  Help us help you...what container are you deploying to?  And why are you making JDBC connections from your JSPs?  Consider learning the MVC pattern and a framework like Spring.

Comment: What container are you using?

Comment: Instructions for Tomcat 6 are here: http://people.apache.org/~fhanik/tomcat/jdbc-pool.html

Comment: Hi I tried the same and created a sample jsp to test the same and i'm getting this error.Error occurred org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp.SQLNestedException: Cannot load JDBC driver class 'com.sybase.jdbc3.jdbc.SybDriver'

Comment: copy the jdbc connector jar file to tomcat's library folder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like stated in comments, you can check [THIS Documentation](http://people.apache.org/~fhanik/tomcat/jdbc-pool.html).