# Usage of Connection object in java

Tags: java

I have a requirement that involves me to call aroung 30 -40 separate functions housing sql queries and update and/or insert.
In this case how can i get the connection object.
Am i suppose to create at one place and pass the connection object to all the 30 functions  or do i create the connection object in the function itself.
There are many updates happening in these queries in separate functions and time is of the essence.
So how do i create the connection object and use the same connection object over and over again without creating a new one.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Connection_pool

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/jndi/tutorial/ldap/connect/pool.html

Answer (score 1):

Specify an additional parameter of type `Connection` in the functions and pass the existing connection to the functions when you are calling them.

Answer (score 1):

You can save yourself a lot of plumbing (and pain) by using the database connection pooling library offered by Apache Commons: http://commons.apache.org/dbcp/

PS: you appear to have asked this question in the past - see [Setting up a jdbc connection pool for sybase](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9170922/setting-up-a-jdbc-connection-pool-for-sybase) - did you follow the advice given there?

Comment: Yes i did follow the advice and it worked,but i set up that pool for jsp/servlets can i use the same pool for pure java programs as well.

Comment: To be honest, I don't know the answer to that. Give it a go and see what happens and come back and tell us so we can learn, too, please.